# Excel Macro to replace numeric zip code with county name

Tags: replace, zip

Issue - We have a spreadsheet with thousands of addresses but no counties.

Goal - We would like to add counties into each record.  We can identify counties using Zip Codes and have a list of Zip Codes and county names.

What I've tried so far - The county names are in Column A and it's corresponding Zip Code is in Column B.  I copied the address list into the same spreadsheet starting with their Zip Codes in Column D.

[image]

I wrote the following simple macro to compare and replace Zip Codes with County names.  It runs but doesn't seem to replace anything.  I don't get any errors, so I'm not sure where the problem is.  Any ideas?

```
  Public Sub Take_Two_Replace_Zip_With_Name()

  Dim LastBCell As Long
  Dim B As Integer
  Dim Bcell As Range

  LastBCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row

  For B = LastBCell To 2 Step -1
  Set Bcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(B, 2)

  If Bcell = Bcell.Offset(0, 2) Then Bcell.Offset(0, 2) = Bcell.Offset(0, -1)
  Next B

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I worked it out myself:

```
  For Each Bcell In Range("B2:B100").Cells

  Columns("D:D").Cells.Replace What:=Bcell, Replacement:=Bcell.Offset(0, -1).Value,          LookAt:=xlPart, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
          ReplaceFormat:=False

  Next Bcell
```